# Why UIView transitionFromView in animateTransition by iOS7 is ok,but iOS8 has not animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios7, uiview, ios8

I want to make an animation during `presentViewController`:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;
    UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
    UIView* containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView addSubview:toView];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.35;
    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView toView:toView duration:duration options:(self.reverse?UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight) | 
    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}
```

this is working fine on iOS7, but there is no animation on iOS8.

Comment: Zacks did you find a solution ?

Comment: i maked it work by use `[UIView transitionFromView:containerView toView:toView ...`, but it was not the best way.

Answer (score 2):

[`+transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:) does the work of handling the view hierarchy. You shouldn't need `[containerView addSubview:toView]`.

Somewhere in the inners of `+transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` should be the following code:

```
UIView *superview = fromView.superview;
[fromView removeFromSuperview];
[superview addSubview:toView];
```

Have you tried removing the `containerView` code:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;
    UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.35;
    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView toView:toView duration:duration options:(self.reverse?UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight) | 
    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}
```

Comment: i had tried this before, but it did not work, no animation when `presentViewController` on iOS8, but on iOS7 animation was OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off `Use Autolayout` for the view controller that your code is in. It should work now. It works for me. My animations were broken when I set up my project for iOS8, but removing `Auto Layout` allowed them to work.